# setting the value of a drop-down-list onclick via javascript/internet explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, return-value

i have a drop-down-list on a page from which users can select a certain value which then leads to the display of a certain graphic (depending on the selection).

the graphic has an id-tag which includes a value and when clicked on, the script loads another graphic by the name of this value.

on the click-event, the value of the drop-down-list is set by

```
    menu.property("value", this.id);
```

and subsequently the function is called.

this works fine in firefox, but somehow it does not in internet explorer (9&10) as no value is passed. the "this.id" works, the menu.property.value is also set correctly but the explorer just does not pass on this value and i end up with a blank page - so i would be thankful for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every browser has different implementations of JavaScript and the DOM.  Your best bet is to start using a library, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which 'normalizes' most browser differences.